# ElevatedButton nested inside GridView.builder not displaying text

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a CategoryList that I want to return a list of elevated buttons that are built from some JSON data.

The buttons are built however the text does not display inside the buttons. They are drawn in the app when loaded but the text does not appear.

I have tried to modify the style for it but to no avail and I know that the name in print(categories[index].name); is available but it's not being displayed.

The image below illustrates the problem. The top container is a horizontal list of ElevatedButtons but without the text inside displayed. The container beneath that is static to show what is expected.

[image]

Has anyone else run into this issue, if so what was your workaround/solution?

```
class CategoryList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryList({Key? key, required this.categories}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Category> categories;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20),
      itemCount: categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
          print(categories[index].id);
          print(categories[index].name);
        },
            child: Text(categories[index].name,
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontStyle: FontStyle
                        .normal)),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.deepPurple),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );


  }
}
```

Comment: did you check textstyle( color : ?) ?

Comment: I did try to add textStyle: Color: Color.white, to the ButtonStyle on the ElevatedButton but my IDE throwing errors when doing that. The text isn't being rendered inside the button. I am updating this question to illustrate with two containers, the top one show the buttons missing the text, the second container underneath is static buttons created for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 1):

`childAspectRatio` == 1.5, try to use a bigger value like 10 to see if it changes.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that solved the problem was to use the switch the GridView.Builder for the ListView.builder and then to change the scroll direction to horizontal.

```
    class CategoryList extends StatelessWidget {
  const CategoryList({Key? key, required this.categories}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Category> categories;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: categories.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 7, right: 7),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text(categories[index]
                  .name),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                backgroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```